# CSS: Font is not displayed correctly in Firefox

Tags: css, fonts

I integrated a font into my web project. Here comes the CSS code:

```
@font-face {

font-family: 'vladimirscriptefregular';

src: url('fonts/vladimirscriptef-webfont.eot');

src: url('fonts/vladimirscriptef-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),

     url('fonts/vladimirscriptef-webfont.woff') format('woff'),

     url('fonts/vladimirscriptef-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),

     url('fonts/vladimirscriptef-webfont.svg#vladimirscriptefregular') format('svg');

font-weight: normal;

font-style: normal;

}
```

My problem is that the font is not displayed in Firefox - instead, Times New Roman is displayed. In all other browsers the font is displayed correctly.

Does anyone see what's missing in my code?

Comment: has the woff version of your file become corrupted or not loaded properly?

Comment: @pete: I don't know, how can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
    @font-face {

    font-family: 'vladimirscriptefregular';
   -moz-font-family:'vladimirscriptefregular';

    src: url('fonts/vladimirscriptef-webfont.eot');

    src: url('fonts/vladimirscriptef-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),

         url('fonts/vladimirscriptef-webfont.woff') format('woff'),

         url('fonts/vladimirscriptef-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),

         url('fonts/vladimirscriptef-webfont.svg#vladimirscriptefregular') format('svg');

    font-weight: normal;
   -moz-font-weight:normal

    font-style: normal;
    -moz-font-style:normal

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a list of fonts which can be used in its whitelist.

1. It can be accessed by typing "about:config" in the address bar.
2. Then search for "font.system.whitelist".
3. Here add your font name which must be present in the Font folder.

For windows the default location is "C:\Windows\Fonts"